# DBunit can't find tables defined on dataset

Tags: database, unit-testing, postgresql, dbunit

I have a dataset (defined in xml) and i am using PostGreSQL, POJOs annotated with JPA, and DbUnit with Junit for tests.

When the test runs, it creates the tables and sequences in the database, but when it starts to read the dataset (xml) with the table definitions and columns, it fires the following error
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException "nameoftable"  I tried to put the name of the table with all caps and normal caps, and it won't work. The table was created in the public schema, and then i tried to define in the xml the table as public."nameoftable" but it also won't work.... any ideas?

I tried to run this tests with DUnit in the following versions: 2.2.2, 2.3.0, and 2.4.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With DBUnit you can either use a specific schema to test against, or a full database (with potentially multiple schema). If you use the latter you need to specify the schema in the dataset when importing/exporting or it can get itself confused; in PostgreSQL at least, I've not tried it with anything else.

To enforce this add the following code in:

```
if (strSchema == null || strSchema.isEmpty()) {
    conn = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
    conn.getConfig().setProperty(
            "http://www.dbunit.org/features/qualifiedTableNames", true);
}
else
    conn = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection, strSchema);
```

The important bit is the setting of the property; the rest is something I use to make the connection relevant to the DB or schema (based upon a schema name extracted from the hibernate config XML).